# MPAndroidChart - Setting a fixed interval on X axis for a time value

Tags: mpandroidchart

I am trying to display a time on my X axis with a fixed interval. Currently the X axis is not behaving like [I want it to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcXiA.png). I'm trying to have an interval of 5 minutes. When I [zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7Tqv.png) in my points are at the right timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use setGranularity API:

```
xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
xAxis.setGranularity(5 * 60 * 1000); // if time is in ms
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this has no effect. I have been trying to mess with the granularity but it never changes anything in my chart

Comment: Nevermind ! If I set the interval to something bigger like 30 minutes it is working. Thank you very much

Comment: Then next question would be how to show x-axis value only for shown label?